# yAxis doesn't appear

Tags: css, d3.js

In the following code, I am creating and calling x and y Axes d3 elements as svg groups:

```
var svg = d3.select("#right-section").append("svg").attr("width",600).attr("height",600);
var flatInputMatrix = [1,1,1,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,2,0,4,4,0,0,0,5,5,0,1,0,2,2];
var m = 5;
var r = 3;    

var counter = -1;

var data = flatInputMatrix.map(function(d, i) {
  i % m === 0 ? counter++ : null;
  return {
    column: i % m,
    row: counter,
    value: d
  };
});

var scaleX = d3.scalePoint().domain(['Matrix', 'Alien', 'Serenity', 'Casablanca', 'Amelie'])
.range([15, 220]);

var scaleY = d3.scalePoint().domain(['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3', 'User 4', 'User 5', 'User 6', 'User 7'])
.range([15, 370]);

var xAxis = d3.axisTop(scaleX);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(scaleY);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,20)")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")
  .attr("class", "yAxis")
  .call(yAxis);

var numbers = svg.selectAll("numbers").data(data).enter().append("text")
    .attr("x",function(d,i) { return (i % m)*50 + 10 + r; })
    .attr("y",function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i / m) *50+50; })
    .style("opacity", function(d) {
        if (d.value > 0) {return 1}
        else {return 0.4} 
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        var column = d.column;
        var row = d.row;
        numbers.filter(function(d) {
            return d.column === column
        })
    })
```

The xAxis here renders perfectly, but I don't see the yAxis. Inspecting the area says the elements are there, and the console displays no errors. Here is the css for reference as well:

```
.xAxis path,
.xAxis line,
.yAxis path,
.yAxis line  {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.xAxis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: red;
}

.yAxis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Can you post on a jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: Can you post your full code? where is `r` and `m` defined?

Comment: added r and m. Apologies I had taken them out thinking they weren't being used in that code. Having a hard time setting up a jsfiddle that works, here is my draft: https://jsfiddle.net/fredbastiat/k700medo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y-axis` is being created but is crammed to the left because of the way your elements are positioned right now. I've made some minor changes to make the positioning of the different elements better. You can adjust further as per your needs.

1. Updated the range for the `y-scale` to constrict it to match the positioning of your matrix `text` elements

   ```
   var scaleY = d3.scalePoint().domain(['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3', 'User 4', 'User 5', 'User 6', 'User 7'])
   .range([45, 350]);
   ```
2. Pushed the Y axis further to the right

   ```
   var gY = svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(60,0)") //pushed right to start at 60
     .attr("class", "yAxis")
     .call(yAxis);
   ```
3. Added some padding to your text elements when they're being appended so they align properly.

   ```
   var numbers = svg.selectAll("numbers").data(data).enter().append("text")
           .attr("x",function(d,i) { return (i % m)*50 + 10 + r + 80; }) //added padding of 80
   ```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a8hqb08y/

P.S. I would suggest using margins for better flexibility with positioning elements so you dont have to worry about things being cut off.

Comment: just the answer I was looking for. Thank you!